# Text value of input xml element as final xslt output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a scenario where the input(source) xml is having an element which contains a valid well formed xml as string. I am trying to write an xslt that would give me the text value of that desired element which contains the payload xml. In essence, output should only be text of the element that contains it. Here is what I am trying, am I missing something obvious here. I am using xslt 1.0
Thanks.

Input xml:

```
    <BatchOrders xmlns="http://Microsoft.ABCD.OracleDB/STMT">
    <BatchOrdersRECORD>
        <BatchOrdersRECORD>
            <ActualPayload>
                &lt;PersonName&gt;
                &lt;PersonGivenName&gt;CaptainJack&lt;/PersonGivenName&gt;
                &lt;PersonMiddleName&gt;Walter&lt;/PersonMiddleName&gt;
                &lt;PersonSurName&gt;Sparrow&lt;/PersonSurName&gt;
                &lt;PersonNameSuffixText&gt;Sr.&lt;/PersonNameSuffixText&gt;
                &lt;/PersonName&gt;
            </ActualPayload>
        </BatchOrdersRECORD>
    </BatchOrdersRECORD>
</BatchOrders>
```

Xslt:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()|@*" name="sourcecopy" mode="xml-to-string">
        <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="xml-to-string-called-template">
        <xsl:param name ="param1">
            <xsl:element name ="DestPayload">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping ="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name ="sourcecopy"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping ="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:param>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output:

```
 <PersonName>
    <PersonGivenName>CaptainJack</PersonGivenName>
    <PersonMiddleName>Walter</PersonMiddleName>
    <PersonSurName>Sparrow</PersonSurName>
    <PersonNameSuffixText>Sr.</PersonNameSuffixText>
</PersonName>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the `mode="xml-to-string"`?

Change

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*" name="sourcecopy" mode="xml-to-string">
    <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*" name="sourcecopy">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Would this template suffice?

Comment: Yep, got it. Works like a charm. Also, realized why it wasn't working before. Thanks much.